# .htaccess for an SPA, rewrite incoming requests to index.html, except for static resources

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, configuration

**EDIT 1** Thank you very much for your responsiveness and patience!.

I am developing a SPA router, so everything happens in index.html. It uses HTML5 History API to rewrite the history and it would be awesome to create SEO friendly URLs.

Some sections are already on the index.html and others are loaded dynamically with ajax or fetch (if that matters)

The app has the next basic directory structure

```
assets/ 
css/
img/
js/
modules/
partials/
vendor/
index.html
```

Now in the router mainly there are sections and subsections, I am rewriting sections as a subdirectory, and subsections as sub-subdirectory

```
example.com/index.html <--- where the magic happens
```

But index.html is also ugly, it would be preferable to rewrite it to (not really needed as it happens naturally, but nice to have)

```
example.com R=301 <permanent
```

Then, when the user navigates to a section the url will be rewritten by history api as:

```
example.com/customers
```

But if the user reloads the website, he gets error 404

Then, when the user navigates to a subsection of that section he will see in the url bar

```
example.com/customers/casestudy
```

But again, if the user reloads, he gets error 404

What I want is to permanently re-write those URLs to index.html and its router/state manager will restore(load/show) the correct state.

The goal of this, is that URLs are SEO friendly and that search engines can index correctly each section of the website. Also if we need to hand a URL of our site to a customer/partner/stakeholder/anybody

```
example.com/mydata is better than example.com/index.html/#/dataFragment25654789
```

Thanks in advance

***EDIT 02***
The next .htaccess works fine

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

except when trying to load a subsection

example.com/customer/mydata

Then it gets uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '<' the same as @MrWhite answer

***OLD QUESTION***

*I want to permanently **rewrite** requests to any file or subdirectory to my `index.html` as it will dispatch the correct views, but preserving the subdirectory structure, no files allowed. I can't get it to work especially with sub-subdirectories
 - `example.com/index.html` or `anyother.file` ---> `example.com/`
 - `example.com/mydirectory/` or `example.com/mydirectory/anyfile.file` to `/index.html` URL should look `example.com/mydirectory`
 - `example.com/mydirectory/mydirectory` or `example.com/mydirectory/anyfile.file` to `/index.html` URL should look `example.com/mydirectory/mydirectory`*

Comment: What requests for static resources... images, CSS, JS, etc. should these also be rewritten to `index.html`?

Comment: Well, it could be good to avoid hotlinking, files could be redirected to a file called hotlinking.html, except for search engines

Comment: Presumably `example.com/mydirectory/anyfile.file` in the last example should read `example.com/mydirectory/mydirectory/anyfile.file`. (?)

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are suggesting is not possible. You can't make the URL look-like `example.com/mydirectory` when you are requesting `example.com/mydirectory/any.file` (where `any.file` is literally _any file_) as you are removing necessary information from the URL that is required to perform the routing later. eg. Given the URL `example.com/mydirectory`, how do you map this back to `example.com/mydirectory/any.file` or `example.com/mydirectory/another.file`? (You can't - it's a one to many relationship.)

Comment: @mrWhite Thank you for your responsiveness and patience, I have edited the question, I am assessing, what is possible and what is not, to adapt the application.

Comment: Minor point... what's inside `/assets`? CSS, JS and images are generally considered "assets", but these have there own directories outside of `/assets`?

Comment: Multimedia files, audio, video, might be txt or even. Json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds (from your updated question) that you "simply" need a standard front-controller type pattern... rewrite everything to `/index.html` (in the document root) except for requests to static resources.

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Allow mod_dir to serve index.html when requesting the directory
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Front-controller (exclude static resources)
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets|css|img|js|modules|partials|vendor)/
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

`index.html` must then look at the requested URL in order to determine how to route the request.

Note that for any requests involving multiple path segments like `/customers/casestudy` then you will need to ensure you are using root-relative URLs (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs (scheme + hostname) to your static resources (JS, CSS, images, etc.). Any *relative* URLs will naturally be relative to the client-side URL and will likely fail to resolve.

The first `RewriteRule` above prevents the following rule being reprocessed after the initial rewrite, to prevent a rewrite loop (and minor optimisation).

The condition that checks the requested URL against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable ensures we don't rewrite any resources in the known subdirectories. This is a more optimal way of checking that the file (or directory) does not exist on the filesystem before rewriting, since filesystem checks are relatively expensive. However, on systems that don't necessarily have a concisely defined structure then the filesystem check may be necessary.

> But `index.html` is also ugly, it would be preferable to rewrite it to (not really needed as it happens naturally, but nice to have)

Yes, you don't need to specify `/index.html` in the URL as mod_dir will issue an internal subrequest for `index.html` when requesting the root directory (that's what the `DirectoryIndex index.html` directive does).

However, you could issue an external redirect if `/index.html` is requested directly by the user (or inadvertently linked to by 3rd parties / search engines). Internally you should be linking to `/`, not `/index.html` - as you don't want to redirect normal users.

For example, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive (and before the *front-controller*):

```
# Redirect "/index.html" to "/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=302,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we don't get a redirect loop (since the later rule rewrites the request back to `index.html`). `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not set on the initial request and is set to "200" after the first successful rewrite.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to 301 (permanent) after you have confirmed that this works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Comment: When using this, javascript can't initialize, Unexpected token '<' I guess when index.html tries to get example.com/js/main.js it gets index html instead

Comment: Seems like the title of the question is also not the best description of the problem

Comment: That sounds like you are using a _relative_ path in your client-side code? Specifically, a relative path in your AJAX call. For what URL are you getting that error? When using URL-rewriting you need to make sure all your URLs are root-relative... to all your static resources, JS code and CSS. Since `/customers` and `/customers/casestudy` need to access the same resources.

Comment: The code in your edited question is really no different to the code in my answer. Except you are explicitly checking for the existence of the file being requested (filesystem checks are "more expensive"). If all your resources are contained in the specific subdirectories you mentioned then you might as well just create exceptions for these subdirectories (as I have done) since this will be more efficient.

Comment: Everything is called relative to root, it happens even without Ajax, the app won't even load the basic css/main.css it also says its the wrong Mime Type

Comment: "it happens even without Ajax" - Although the error you quoted, "Unexpected token '<' " - is a JS error, looks like a JSON conversion problem (which can happen on a 404). Is there any difference when using the code in my answer vs the code in your "EDIT 02"?

Comment: The code in my edited answer works fine to redirect sections

example.com/customers works as it should

Subsections get the error
example.com/customers/whatever


Is not a json error, as it happens even if I just load one Javascript `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` that only contains console.log('heya');

Seems like if the script tag instead of getting the js it should, receives instead the same index.html that's why it shows the opening < of index.html (sorry i was using cellphone to answer)

Comment: `src="js/main.js"` - That's the problem. That is a _relative_ path, not a root-relative path. You need to reference the resources using a root-relative path - with a slash prefix (or specify an absolute URL). ie. `src="/js/main.js"`. Sorry, there was a slash missing in the code in my answer, the _CondPattern_ should have read `!^/(assets|css....`, not `!^(assets|css....`, now updated.

Comment: With `src="js/main.js"` and you request `/customers/casestudy` then the browser will try to request `/customers/js/main.js`. This would end up be rewritten by the front-controller (which I assume would ultimately trigger a 404 in your code).

Comment: Thank you very much, you're very kind!, and definitively your solution is much more performant, doing stress test right now! We should rename the title of this question

Comment: What is the syntax at Laravel that serve a React app? index.blade.php ...